# Group by date and sum columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that has a poor design choice that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Day': ['2021-03-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-02', '2021-03-02', '2021-03-03'],
    'Name': ['Sam', 'Sam', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Steve'],
    'Fruit':['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Banana'],
    '2021-03-01':['2', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
    '2021-03-02': ['3', '5', '4', '2', '1'],
    '2021-03-03':['7', '3', '2', '1', '4']})

df
          Day   Name   Fruit 2021-03-01 2021-03-02 2021-03-03
0  2021-03-01    Sam   Apple          2          3          7
1  2021-03-01    Sam   Apple          1          5          3
2  2021-03-02   Jack  Banana          0          4          2
3  2021-03-02  Steve   Apple          1          2          1
4  2021-03-03  Steve  Banana          1          1          4
```

I want, for each date in `Day`, corresponding to the date in the columns that have the same column name as the value of `Day`, grouping the other variables and aggregating them by sum.
For example, if the `Day` value is '2021-03-01', then in the '2021-03-01' column, I'll sum the values (nr of apples and nbr of bananas in this column).

It want the result dataframe to look like this :

```
         Date   Name  nrApples  nrBananas
0  2021-03-01    Sam         3          0
1  2021-03-02   Jack         0          4
2  2021-03-02  Steve         2          0
3  2021-03-03  Steve         0          4
```

The problem is that I have a lot of these date columns, and I don't know how to check if the value in the `Day` columns is the same as the name of a column, and aggregate the values of it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melt the columns, compare the `Day` column to the `variable` column that contains the Days, groupby, aggregate(sum), unstack, and reset index:

```
(df
 .melt(['Day', 'Name', 'Fruit'])
 .loc[lambda df: df.Day.eq(df.variable)]
 .astype({"value": int})
 .groupby(['Day', 'Name', 'Fruit'])['value']
 .sum()
 .unstack(fill_value = 0)
 .add_prefix("nr")
 .reset_index()
 .rename_axis(columns = None)
 )
 
Fruit         Day   Name  nrApple  nrBanana
0      2021-03-01    Sam        3         0
1      2021-03-02   Jack        0         4
2      2021-03-02  Steve        2         0
3      2021-03-03  Steve        0         4
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you!! Do you know if I can modify it if I want to sum for ALL the dates columns? (no matter if `Day` is the same or no)

Comment: You should be able to modify and. If you have any issues pls ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fn(x):
    return (
        x.set_index("Fruit")
        .loc[:, x.Day.iat[0]]
        .astype(int)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .sum()
        .to_dict()
    )


df = (
    df.groupby(["Day", "Name"])
    .apply(fn)
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .add_prefix("nr")
    .reset_index()
    .fillna(0)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Day   Name  nrApple  nrBanana
0  2021-03-01    Sam      3.0       0.0
1  2021-03-02   Jack      0.0       4.0
2  2021-03-02  Steve      2.0       0.0
3  2021-03-03  Steve      0.0       4.0
```