# Group Daily Date Columns by Month and Sum Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this (**but with 565 date columns**):

```
    County  2021-03-01 2021-03-02 2021-03-03 ...
0   Solano           2          3          7
1    Davis           1          5          3
2    Weber           0          4          2
3     Yuba           1          2          1
4    Marin         100          1          4
```

What I'm trying to do is roll together the values for each day into a monthly sum. It's a very wide table, so I don't really have the patience or desire to do something like this manually. Ultimately, I want my data to look something more like this:

```
    County  2021-03 2021-04 2021-05 ...
0   Solano       12      24      60
1    Davis        9      16      30
2    Weber        6      14      21
3     Yuba        4      12      27
4    Marin      105     200    1021
```

Or, if it's easier, something like this instead:

```
    County  Year_Month  Sum
0   Solano     2021-03   12
1    Davis     2021-03    9
2    Weber     2021-03    6
3     Yuba     2021-03    4
4    Marin     2021-03  105
```

I have looked into using [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to make grouping and aggregating the dataframe the way I want to, but I haven't found enough examples of its usage to grasp if that's the best path forward. I found a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960847/group-by-date-and-sum-columns), but I couldn't quite understand the application of `pd.melt()` without a singular and generic date column.

I'm looking for some help getting to a monthly sum but just need a little more guidance. Any ideas?

Comment: is it possible to have the source code: ``df.to_dict('records'``. a small subset would do fine

Comment: @sammywemmy The dict itself would be far too large to post here since a single dict is 575 key-value pairs. Sorry!

Comment: no worries, i feel a groupby without the melt would be more efficient, since there wont be so many rows to deal with

Comment: @sammywemmy yup agree with you.....didn't noticed that there is no need of `melt()` only `groupby()` is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there only 1 string name and others are date like names in columns and your country column contains unique values:

You can try `set_index()`+columns attribute+`groupby()` :

```
df=df.set_index('County')
df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns).strftime("%Y-%m")
df=df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).sum().reset_index()
```

OR

for your updated question use:

```
df=(df.melt('County',var_name='Year_Month',value_name='Sum')
      .assign(Year_Month=lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x['Year_Month']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m"))
      .groupby(['County','Year_Month']).sum().reset_index())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just a side note, but I had to adjust the lambda that converts the date columns to actual datetime objects because the data types were all `int64`. That `assign()` method instead looked like this for me: `.assign(date=lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x['date'].astype(str)).dt.strftime("%Y-%m"))`.

Comment: @Kevin ohh..happy coding **:)**